# Document-picker keeps showing up even though persistence is set (in SAF - Storage Access Framework)

Tags: android, file-permissions, persistent-storage, storage-access-framework

Using Android 6.0.1, API 23,

I successfully implemented reading a file from a storage-location that the user picks in the document-picker of SAF ([Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)).

Now, I would like to use the `Persist permissions` that SAF allows in order to allow my App to always pick the same file (but without any document-picker window [and sub-windows] popping in all the time).

I somehow succeeded in implementing the Persist-permissions (as shown in the [SAF-doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)) (...for that, see my code example below...) - But questions came up:

1. In spite of persistence-permission working - why does the document-picker window keep popping up? Once the file is picked by the user - from this moment on - I would like to simply get the file content without any picker window coming to foreground. Is this possible? And if yes, how?
   (I can tell that persistence permission is somehow working since the file gets read immediately without the user having to pick again. But still this nasty picker window should not have to come up - or does it?)
2. Is it possible to keep SAF persistence-permission even if my App gets closed or stopped? If yes, how?

Here is the code sample that does get the file content, including my trial with the persistence permission:

Inside a StorageClientFragment Class:

```
public String locationFileContent;

public void performFileSearch() {
    Intent openDocumentIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    openDocumentIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    openDocumentIntent.setType("text/plain");
    openDocumentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                                | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(openDocumentIntent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {

    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();

            // Here is my Persist-permission trial !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            getActivity().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            try {
                this.locationFileContent = readTextFromUri(uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private String readTextFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Creating the Fragment gets done in MainActivity:

```
StorageClientFragment storageClientFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGTAG) == null ) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        storageClientFragment = new StorageClientFragment();
        transaction.add(storageClientFragment, FRAGTAG);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Calling the FileSearch is done when a Test-Button is clicked:

```
public void TestingButtonClicked(View view) {
    this.storageClientFragment.performFileSearch();
    String stringFileContent = this.storageClientFragment.locationFileContent;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Back in Main, Content = " + stringFileContent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The above code works nicely. But again, how can I stop the SAF document-picker window from showing up all the time (even though persist permission is set)?

Answer (score 0):

> why does the document-picker window keep croping up ?

Presumably because you keep starting an `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` activity. If you do not want to ask the user to pick a document, do not start this activity.

> I would like to simply get the file content without any picker-window coming to foreground. Is this possible ? And if yes, how ??

The same way that you got the content originally: pass the `Uri` to `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`.

If you are using `takePersistableUriPermissions()` to aim for long-lived access to the content, it is still **your job** to hold onto the `Uri`. This is not significantly different than how this sort of thing works in other environments (e.g., remembering the user's history of local file paths for a desktop OS program).

Since a `Uri` can be trivially converted to and from a `String`, saving the `Uri` somewhere (database, `SharedPreferences`, or other file) is not especially difficult.

> Is it possible to keep SAF persistance-permission even if my App gets closed or stopped ? If yes, how ??

`takePersistableUriPermission()`, as you have already implemented.

Comment: Thank you! That clarifies a lot. This is all very new to me and I was not aware that the URI is unique and can be kept (with SharedPrefs for example). And if I understood correctly, the takePersistableUriPermission() somehow double-checks with a hiddenly safed flag and tells the App that it is good to go (or not, if user never picked anything in the document-picker). Quite nice - all that. I will try to implement this. Thanks again !